# How to connect Storage with Access Keys (managed by Azure Vault) in Azure Function code

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-functions, azure-storage

In Azure have created a storage account.
Then also created Key Vault.
Followed below link to allow Azure Vault to manage Storage access keys.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/secrets/overview-storage-keys-powershell

IN Azure function i want to access this storage blob using key1 or key2. How to get access to key1 or key2 now?

Comment: Which programming language are you using?

Comment: we are using C#, dotnet core

Comment: Have you tried this to retrieve your storage keys? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/secrets/quick-create-net#authenticate-and-create-a-client

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`StorageSharedKeyCredential`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.storage.blobs.blobserviceclient.-ctor?view=azure-dotnet#Azure_Storage_Blobs_BlobServiceClient__ctor_System_Uri_Azure_Storage_StorageSharedKeyCredential_Azure_Storage_Blobs_BlobClientOptions_) to connect storage with accountKey.

```
StorageSharedKeyCredential storageSharedKeyCredential = new StorageSharedKeyCredential(accountName, accountKey);

BlobServiceClient blobServiceClient = new BlobServiceClient(new Uri("https://"+accountName+".blob.core.windows.net"), storageSharedKeyCredential);
```